# How can we dynamically Sorting & Grouping data from DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and i see that data sorting done by the sort key value. Is there a way how we can sort data for any attribute with in an item irrespective of sortkey. And i am using nodejs with DynamoDB for my project.

May i know how can i achieve the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't need to re-partition your data, the first way to do this is to create a LSI (local secondary index) with your new sort key.

But unlike SQL you can't do ad hoc queries, when you design how you are setting up your table you already have to know much about what queries and transactions you will have, in general you shouldn't need to make an LSI every time you want to search, I recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE).